# learn angular 1.3 or wait for 2.0

Tags: angularjs

I just found out about angular j.s 2.0.  I have only been studying 1.3 for the past 3 weeks and am considering switching to another framework as I hear 2.0 will be very different (fearing what I am studying will be useless in a year).  I am curious what take a more experienced programmer would take?  I have only been programming in JS for 6 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, Angular 1.3 seems a bit unstable and buggy and could prove frustrating sometimes. I would recommend starting with even 1.2.26. Solid experience built on this one should be easily transferred to newer version :)

What is more, almost all the tutorials you can find now on the Internet are compatible with aforementioned version. Please refer to "Learn" section on Angular website. For starters, I would recommend learning through codeschool examples :)

AngularJS approach to MVC, two-way data binging, testing and much more isn't something that will be forgotten or will change much - these reasons are enough in my opinion to start from older one.